# jsPDF fromHTML image (to large) and page margin-bottom (not working)

Tags: jspdf, image-size, page-size

I just implemented jspdf in a page, where users work with an editor and then want to be able to print the result. When I tested some example content, I run in to that problem the images are not displayed in there orignial size. They are scaled/displayed so large, that they are lager then the width of the page.

Also I had a problem with the page height/margin-bottom. If the content is to large for a page, then there will be no margin at the bottom of the page. So if for what ever reason an elemtent seems to be too large for a page, this element goes until the end of the page.

I googled a lod, but I couldn't find a solution to avoid that too large elements go until the border of the page. 
And I also could not find something, for how to set an image to it's original or max-size when I don't know the content of the page.

Here is js code and an example page: [jsfiddle-example](https://jsfiddle.net/ebyjv3q7/19/)

```
$(".printPdf").click(function () {
    var pdfdoc = new jsPDF("portrait");
    var getPageTitle = $("#page-title");
    var pageTitle = (getPageTitle != "")? getPageTitle : "Document";
    var contentClass = ".page-content";
    var $pageContent = $(contentClass);
    var margins = {
        top: 10,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 15,
        width: 180
    };


    pdfdoc.setDisplayMode('original');
    pdfdoc.fromHTML($pageContent.get(0), margins.left, margins.top, {
        "width": margins.width,
        "text-align": "unset"
    }, function () { pdfdoc.save(pdfdoc.pageTitle + ".pdf") }, margins);

});
```